# CloudFormation AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate automated certificate validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-route53

According the AWS docs at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-certificatemanager-certificate-domainvalidationoption.html#cfn-certificatemanager-certificate-domainvalidationoption-hostedzoneid) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/aws-certificate-manager-extends-automation-certificate-issuance-via-cloudformation/) I should be able to automate a certificate creation *and validation* using cloudformation. Apparently when you specify a `HostedZoneId` in the `DomainValidationOptions`, it is supposed to create the required DNS record to complete the validation (at least that is what it seems from the very vague documentation). My CF template for the cert looks like this:

```
Resources:
  MyAPICert:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: xxxx.dev.mydomain.io
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: mydomain.io
          HostedZoneId: /hostedzone/Z03XXXXXXXXXXXX
      ValidationMethod: DNS
```

'mydomain.io' (changed of course) was registered using AWS as registrar as the documents say must be the case for automated validation to work.

This template above is included in a serverless.yml as a resource. However, when I deploy, the stack creation is just stuck waiting for the DNS record - i.e. it does not add the required CNAME entry as I understand it is *supposed* to do and as such the stack is stuck.

Has anyone gotten this feature to work?

And, yes, I know about the 3rd party custom resources that try to do the same thing, I don't want to use them if CF is supposed to do this natively now.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the HostedZoneId is supposed to be without the `/hostedzone/` prefix which is what I got from the output `aws route53 list-hosted-zones`: ```{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/Z03XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Name": "mydomain.io.",
}```

Comment: Hmm..nope...behaves the same even if I omit the `/hostedzone/` prefix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hit the same issue. You need to specify the full domain name including the host in the `DomainValidationOptions` `DomainName` parameter, and just specify the hosted zone id:

```
Resources:
  MyAPICert:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: xxxx.dev.mydomain.io
      DomainValidationOptions:
       - DomainName: xxxx.dev.mydomain.io
         HostedZoneId: Z03XXXXXXXXXXXX
      ValidationMethod: DNS
```

In my testing, the Route53 validation record was added about a minute after running the stack, and the domain successfully validated itslef after about 15 minutes.

Comment: By golly that was it! Would be nice if that detail were documented somewhere! Thanks to you, it is now documented in the 'unofficial' documentation for anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: There is a [note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-certificatemanager-certificate-domainvalidationoption.html#cfn-certificatemanager-certificate-domainvalidationoption-hostedzoneid) under the HostedZoneId property of the DomainValidationOption documentation that reads: "The ListHostedZones API returns IDs in the format '/hostedzone/Z111111QQQQQQQ', but CloudFormation requires the IDs to be in the format 'Z111111QQQQQQQ'".

Comment: it works! keep an eye on your email for change authorisations too

Comment: Thank you so much - it works! i've been fighting this all day!

Answer (score 3):

If this is stuck as in progress for a long time, it could be that you are using a Private Hosted Zone when you need to use the Public one. Probably you don't use a private CA.
That process should take 2-3 minutes, not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I just deployed the below template to CloudFormation and it successfully created the validation DNS records and authorised the certificate.

If you were to pass the parameters `SiteDnsZoneName=mydomain.io.` and `SiteDnsZoneId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU` it would create a SAN cert that covers both `mydomain.io` and `*.mydomain.io`

```
{
    "Description": "Deploy wildcard SAN cert inc bare domain. (Must deploy cert to us-east-1 for CloudFront)",
    "Parameters": {
        "SiteDnsZoneName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": 4,
            "Description": "DNS Zone",
            "Default": "example.com"
        },
        "SiteDnsZoneId": {
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": 8,
            "Description": "DNS Zone Id",
            "Default": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "SiteCertificate": {
            "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
                "DomainName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ".",
                        [
                            "*",
                            {
                                "Ref": "SiteDnsZoneName"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "SubjectAlternativeNames": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "SiteDnsZoneName"
                    }
                ],
                "DomainValidationOptions": [
                    {
                        "DomainName": {
                            "Ref": "SiteDnsZoneName"
                        },
                        "HostedZoneId": {
                            "Ref": "SiteDnsZoneId"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ValidationMethod": "DNS"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to use a cert in CloudFront you have to deploy the cert in us-east-1.

Note 2: Route53 needs to be hosting your DNS Zone, but theres no requirement on AWS being the registrar. Your domain can be registered with any provider, so long as you use the AWS name servers provided by Route53 when you add the zone.

Comment: How long did it take for the CNAME record to be created? I waited up to 30 minutes and no CNAME entry appeared (nor was there an error in the stack).

Comment: Above stack took 6 or 7 mins to deploy (which created the CNAME & created / activated cert). What output/error does it give if you let it time out? What region are you deploying?

Comment: It's never times out, I can try that and leave it for the night. In the log, there is output saying what needs to be put into DNS, but there is nothing in the stack saying that it is doing it (and indeed it does not). Deploying to us-east-2.

Comment: Can you either deploy everything to us-east-1, or deploy just certificate to us-east-1 and use the us-east-1 certificate ARN for your us-east-2 app? Its weird its not erroring - but i suspect its due to region.

Comment: Configured exactly as above but did not work until I changed the DomainName property under DomainValidationOptions to be the same as the DomainName property under the Certificate Properties as @X-Guardian suggested in answer (I know, this does not make sense as I am also using a wildcard domain). When I did this, CFN started creating the CNAME record automatically. However, the stack template still sits there waiting for the cert to be validated. Certificate Manager also shows "Pending validation" in spite of the correctly added CNAME record.

Comment: Making the DomainName properties the same only worked because *.example.com does not include example.com. See RFC 2459 quoted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/88mt3r/when_creating_a_wildcard_certificate_for_a_given/dwlv77p/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): A "*" wildcard character MAY be used as the left-most name component in the certificate. For example, *.example.com would match a.example.com, foo.example.com, etc. but would not match example.com. So I switched it back to my original config and added example.com under SubjectAlternativeNames.